# ODBC/JDBC to REST Framework

Tags: rest

I'm looking to find a framework/tool that will take an SQL query to an ODBC/JDBC connection and generate a REST interface. The idea is to minimize any API development work and reuse existing CRUD SQL. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you consider turning the SQL operations/queries you're attempting to use in the API, into stored procedures. This provides three key functionalities, related to the API endpoint signatures: defined inputs (data types and value domains), and the ability to understand those inputs and filter for SQL injection, and finally, the limitation of SQL entities (tables, views, etc.) exposed in the application/API.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

At that point, the API development, using any of the prime toolkits, is significantly simplified. Swagger, Entity Framework and the base ASP.Net Web API then all can readily access those procedures.